# 13.10 with Raid 5 mount issues

Tags: 13.10, automount, raid5

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 onto an HP Proliant Microserver with a Raid 5 configuration.  Using Mdadm, it found the raid and now auto mounts when I reboot...but...the actual folders aren't appearing to any programs that access them, i.e., Plex, without me first going into the raid first.

So the main raid drive is called DATA, it's on the dock, it shows on reboot, but I have to go in for it to complete the auto mount (I think)

My previous version, 12.something, did this fine.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Same problem suffered with install on blank system.  Refused to install using Raid, so turned raid off in bios and used AHCI and no further issues ocured and installed successufully.